# Do I need "close FILEHANDLE" check for errors?

Tags: perl

does the "or die $!"-part in the "close $fh or die $!;"-line any good?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = 'my_file';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;

print <$fh>;

close $fh or die $!;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your example, as it is at the end of your script and on a file open for reading, it is unncessary.

I'm trying to think if it's necessary when reading a pipe. Normally you close after an EOF condition, so I think it's not necessary either.

However, if you are writing, there are various errors that could be detected at close time. The most simple example is a full disk. This may not be reported until closing the filehandle because of buffering.

You can also `use autodie` (recommended above Fatal, I think).

Answer (score 8):

If the file is open for reading that is not needed.

However, when file is open for writing it is possible that IO buffer could not be flushed at `close`, so it could be useful in that case

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the "or die" should do it.

However in practice checking for errors when closing a file is unnecessary, as the only error that close can ever reasonably give you was "bad file descriptor" i.e. the file wasn't open in the first place - which means it's effectively succeeded anyway.

You could also consider using Fatal. (perldoc Fatal)

Comment: You could also get an error on close if the handle was opened to a pipe and the process terminated with an error.

Comment: You can also get an error from a previous write (if the write was buffered and the error occurred after the system call had returned).